# Не отображается HP бар на объекте в Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

У меня есть на объекте ХП Бар, но когда я запускаю игровую сцену, то ХП БАР отключается. Если я попытаюсь включить, то при попадания пули он снова отключается.

[image: Canvas]

[image: Характеристика]

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private int _health;
    [SerializeField] private int _reward;
    public Player _target;
    private Animator _animator;
    private int _currentHealth;

    public HealthBarEnemy HealthBar;

    public int Reward => _reward;
    public Player Target => _target;

    public event UnityAction<Enemy> Dying;
    private void Start()
    {
        _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        _currentHealth = _health;
        HealthBar.SetHealth(_currentHealth, _health);
    }

    public void Init(Player target)
    {
        _target = target;
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        _health -= damage;
        HealthBar.SetHealth(_currentHealth, _health);

        if (_health <= 0)
        {
            Dying?.Invoke(this);
            _animator.SetTrigger("Death");
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HealthBarEnemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider Slider;
    public Color Low;
    public Color High;
    public Vector3 Offset;

    public void SetHealth(int health, int maxHealth)
    {
        Slider.gameObject.SetActive(health < maxHealth);
        Slider.value = health;
        Slider.maxValue = maxHealth;

        Slider.fillRect.GetComponentInChildren<Image>().color = Color.Lerp(Low, High, Slider.normalizedValue);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Slider.transform.position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.parent.position + Offset);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6kHe.png

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `TakeDamage()` урон отнимается от `_health`, хотя явно должен от `_currentHealth`. Не забудь еще об `if`'е там же.

Чтобы не путаться, лучше переименуй `_health` в что-то вроде `_maxHealth`, как это у тебя в принципе и написано в параметрах к `SetHealth()`.